# MacBook Pro number keys failing most of the time

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

I have a MacBook Pro late 2012 with OS X El Capitan.

Recently the number keys have become very flaky. Most of the time they're not working. They do work at times though, and it's the whole row from <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd>.
<kbd>0</kbd> is working fine. And I'm using the Keyboard Viewer as a workaround.

I found somewhere that it could be because of Mouse Keys, but that's not. Mouse Keys are disabled. I also turned off ShiftIt, but that hasn't helped either.

Also if I switch to another user on the system the number keys are not working. They still work at times though, so I doubt it's a hardware problem. I currently don't have access to a USB or Bluetooth keyboard, but that is the next thing I'll try.  Is there anything else I can try to find out more about this problem in the meanwhile?

Comment: Trying another keyboard is the easiest way to see whether it's hardware or not.  Hard to imagine a software issue that would cause intermittent failure, that's exactly what a hardware failure might do.

Comment: Try booting into safe mode as well, then report back.